# Can not read Config File

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a config file in my project, which I am not able to read in for some reason. Similar code has worked for me in the past. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. I was wondering if someone would be able to have a look and let me know if I am doing something wrong. Please help...

Here's my code:

```
  KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings;
  Configuration config;
  ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
  configFile.ExeConfigFilename = "myProject.exe.config";
  config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
  settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
  this.logFilePath = settings["logFilePath"].Value;
  this.logFilePath = settings["logFileName"].Value;
```

Here's my Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?/>
<configuration>
  <add key="logFilePath" value=".//Results//" />
  <add key="logFileName" value="Output.xml" />
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance,
Harit

Comment: What is the error you are actually receiving?

Comment: The AppSettings Collection is missing from your configuration. You only have the root-level of <configuration> configured. But you are requesting <appsettings> (sp?) in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppSettings Collection is missing from your configuration. You only have the root-level of  configured. But you are requesting  in your code.

Your configuration should be

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="logFilePath" value=".//Results//" />
      <add key="logFileName" value="Output.xml" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

harit, try amending your structure to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?/>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="logFilePath" value=".//Results//" />
     <add key="logFileName" value="Output.xml" />
   <appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Using the `ConfigurationManager` creates the requirement for this exact structure to be present. it should work as planned with the above change.

Answer (score 0):

Read values from different web.config:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"second.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap,ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

ConfigurationSection mySection = config.GetSection("countoffiles");
if (config.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
{
    System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement customSetting =
        config.AppSettings.Settings["countoffiles"];
    if (customSetting != null)
    {
        Response.Write(customSetting.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No countoffiles application string");
    }
}
```